# Does WooCommerce Order Item Meta value need to be a string?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

This question is almost out of pure curiosity.

As stated in the title, does WooCommerce order item meta need to be a String.

Hypothetically speaking could you have meta data that is an array? 
If so, would you need to go about things any differently?

I know that in order to add new meta data you would need to use something along the lines of the following code:

```
wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'myMetaName', 'John Doe', true);
```

But, I would like to know if it is possible to have your meta data be of a different data type.

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: one google search tells me it is possible. Try reading documentation first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Yes it can be also an array.**

if you look into the Database table for **`'_line_tax_data'`** **`meta_key`** you get always a serialized array as **`meta_value`** something like this:

```
a:2:{s:5:"total";a:1:{i:2;s:4:"1.92";}s:8:"subtotal";a:1:{i:2;s:3:"2.4";}}
```

And this is what you get in the source code:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Order Item Meta API - Add term meta.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $item_id
 * @param mixed $meta_key
 * @param mixed $meta_value
 * @param bool $unique (default: false)
 * @return int New row ID or 0
 */
function wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false ) {
    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'order-item' );
    if ( $meta_id = $data_store->add_metadata( $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ) ) {
        $cache_key = WC_Cache_Helper::get_cache_prefix( 'order-items' ) . 'object_meta_' . $item_id;
        wp_cache_delete( $cache_key, 'order-items' );
        return $meta_id;
    }
    return 0;
}
```